# Objects are not valid as a React child when fetching the data

Tags: reactjs, object, fetch

I think I might have a really simple but long question because I couldn't figure the solution out. Anyway, I am trying to fetch data and then display it on the table. For this, my parent component is

```
export default function PriceCoefficient() {
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchPosts = async () => {
      try {
        setLoading(true);
        const res = await Axios({
        });
        if (res.status == 200) {
          setMainPricePosts(res.data.main_price.large_car);
        }
        setLoading(false);
      } catch (err) {
        setError(err.message);
        setLoading(false);
      }
    };
    fetchPosts();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <PanelHeader size="sm" />
      <div className="content">
        <Row>
          <Col xs={12}>
            <Card>
              <CardHeader>
                <CardTitle tag="h4">PRICE COEFFICIENT</CardTitle>
              </CardHeader>
              <CardBody>
                <h4>Main Prices</h4>
                <Table responsive>
                  <thead className="text-primary">
                    <tr>
                      <th>Large Cars</th>
                      <th>X-Large Cars</th>
                      <th>XX-Large Cars</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <PricePostsMainPrice
                    mainPricePosts={mainPricePosts}
                    loading={loading}
                    error={error}
                  />
                </Table>
              </CardBody>
            </Card>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

And I am sending the props to my child component which is

```
return (
    <>
      {loading ? (
        <LoadingBox></LoadingBox>
      ) : error ? (
        showError ? (
          <ErrorBox show={showError} onHide={handleCloseError}></ErrorBox>
        ) : (
          <MessageBox variant="danger">{error}</MessageBox>
        )
      ) : (
        <tbody>
            <tr>
              <InputPrice mainPricePosts={mainPricePosts} handleChange={handleChange} />
            </tr>
        </tbody>
      )}
      <SuccessBox show={show} onHide={handleClose}></SuccessBox>
    </>
  );
```

So at the end of this, I want to show the data in the input box because the second step will be to update the data when it is clicked. So I don't think it is necessary for this question but anyway, here it is also:

```
const InputPrice = ({ handleChange }) => (
    <Form.Control type="number" onChange={handleChange} disabled/>
);

InputPrice.propTypes = {
  handleChange: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

export default InputPrice;
```

The problem is I am getting  **Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.**
Do you see the reason for this error?

If you can help me, I would be really glad. I know it is long but I hope it is clear also. Let me know if you don't understand anything.

Comment: You aren't passing anything to axios. Is that intentional? `const res = await Axios({ });`? Also, where are your `useState` hooks?

Comment: Yes it was. It is just classic API call, I didnt want to write it long

Comment: oh ok. gotcha...

Comment: same for the useState. if you want to know the specific one I can write

Comment: Is an error being thrown? Is `err.message` an object? if so, that would make sense

Comment: I am getting this error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: Right, but here you have `<MessageBox variant="danger">{error}</MessageBox>` if `{error}` is an object, you'd get that error. (I know this is confusing)

Comment: No I think before it renders, I get the error

Comment: Hmmm. In that case, I'm not really sure. Maybe check all your imports and check that you are importing exactly what you mean

Comment: ReactJS accepts only JSX elements to behaviour as a child component. Maybe one of your components is not well implemented. See if one of them has `async` and remove it.

Comment: True and I have no idea why I have this unfortunatelly